# how to mock response from httpclient in c#, Azure functions, how to test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, service, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I have a static azure function that has an httpclient inside of a service.

```
public static void MyAzureFunction ()
{
    ........... 
    // inside run
    var service = new Service(...)

    var result = service.DoSomething(....);
}
```

on the other hand, I have the following:

```
public class Service
{
    ...//my properties
    public Service(...) {...}
    ...
    public Result DoSomething(...)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //configuring httpClient
        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(...);
    }    
}
```

How do I test this?

What I know:

1. the service object is not injected into the Azure function, so I can't send a mock. It is created instead.
2. the Azure function must belong to a static class, therefore I can't use virtual or override on methods to bypass anything and then mock them.

Comment: Can you use `IHttpClientFactory` inside your `Service` class instead of directly creating an `HttpClient` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this like any other program. In comparison, consider a console application. You typically don't test `Main`, because this is where you compose everything. The same goes for an ASP.NET application, where you rarely directly test `Startup`. Rather, you treat these as [Humble Objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/HumbleObject.html). While you don't test them, you also drain them of logic.

Start-up code like that `MyAzureFunction` belongs to that category. While you may not be able to directly unit test that function, you can treat it as your function's [Composition Root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot):

```
public static void MyAzureFunction()
{
   var service = new Service(new Dependency())
   var result = service.Dosomething(...);
}
```

The only thing the Composition Root should do is to compose an object graph and delegate to a single method that does all the work.

This means that you can now test everything else, if you design it accordingly.

Here, for example, we've changed `Service` so that it takes a dependency in its constructor. If you design that dependency so that it is properly polymorphic, you can now test `Service` with [Test Doubles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html).